# how to set id of an element in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to set id of  a form by php, but i can't do it!

```
<?php

$form= $_GET['form'];
echo"
 <form id='$form' class='thisForm form' method='post'>
    <input type ='text' name='name'/>
 </form>"; ?>
```

the output is :

```
<form id="" class="thisForm form" method="post">
```

I have found something, when I use inspect element of browser the id is empty string, but when use page source the id is not empty! 
And when I want to get the id by jQuery it is empty too!

Comment: and where pray tell does that GET array get populated from?

Comment: `echo "<form id='".$form."'....`

Comment: You should read up on [how to prevent XSS attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving any value from the get method(URL) which you want to set as `id` of a form then you have to assign it to a variable like

```
<?php
    $myid= $_GET['form']; // Any name that you want set as id.
 ?>

<form id="<?php echo $myid ?>" class="thisForm form" method="POST">
 <input type ="text" name="name"/>
</form>
```

So `$myid` variable contain a name which you're adding to your form as `id`.

Comment: that kind of defeats the way they're trying to do it now, given they might want to do the echo. You need to explain why theirs is failing which is pretty obvious.

Comment: tnx for let me know.